# Move Laravel project to subdomain where Wordpress is already installed

Tags: laravel, subdomain, setup-deployment

I created a subdomain and move whole project except public folder. Create mysql database and upload my database there. Now, in public_html folder I already have wp files so I created new folder there which I named same as subdomain. So, subdomain is something.something.com and now I have path public_html/something/public where I upload all from public folder. I try to rename files in index.php public foder:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to this:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../something/public/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../something/public/bootstrap/app.php';
```

but still I get this:

[image]

And I edit .env file to find database. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The problem is how your server maps the subdomain to a folder, that entirely depends on the specific server setup.

Comment: Where can I see that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was PHP version mismatched. In local it was 7.1 but on server was 5. When I update on server it worked.